# Changing routes within a components changes the whole page

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have an application where when the user logs in, He/She is taken to dashboard where I have a sidebar in which there are links to various components like (home,search,myaccount), And I have included the BrowserRouter inside that component and defined routes and corresponding components but when I click one of the links the whole page is gone and nothing is shown, However when the page is loaded for the first time the home component gets loaded correctly after that if I click any of the links nothing works properly

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Layout, Menu, Icon, Modal } from "antd";
import jwtDecode from "jwt-decode";
import {
  withRouter,
  Link,
  Switch,
  BrowserRouter,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Search from "./components/Search";
import MyAccount from "./components/MyAccount";

const { Header, Sider, Content } = Layout;

class Dashboard extends Component {
  state = {
    collapsed: false,
    modalVisible: false
  };

  toggle = () => {
    this.setState({
      collapsed: !this.state.collapsed,
      current: 1
    });
  };

  toggleModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      modalVisible: true
    });
  };

  handleOk = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem("user");
    this.setState(
      {
        modalVisible: false
      },
      () => {
        this.props.history.push("/");
      }
    );
  };

  handleCancel = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        modalVisible: false,
        current: 1
      },
      () => {
        console.log(this.state);
      }
    );
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("user");

    if (token) {
      const decoded = jwtDecode(token);

      if (Date.now() < decoded.exp) {
        console.log("logged out");
        this.props.history.push("/");
      } else {
        console.log("logged in");
        this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
      }
    } else {
      this.props.history.push("/");
    }
  }

  handleClick = e => {
    this.setState({
      current: e.key
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Layout>
        <Sider
          trigger={null}
          collapsible
          collapsed={this.state.collapsed}
          style={{ minHeight: "100vh" }}
        >
          <Menu
            theme="dark"
            mode="inline"
            defaultSelectedKeys={["1"]}
            style={{ marginTop: "5rem" }}
          >
            <Menu.Item key="1">
              <Link to="dashboard/home" exact="true">
                <Icon type="home" />
                <span>Home</span>
              </Link>
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="2">
              <Link to="dashboard/search" exact="true">
                <Icon type="search" />
                <span>Search</span>
              </Link>
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="3">
              <Link to="dashboard/my-account" exact="true">
                <Icon type="user" />
                <span>My account</span>
              </Link>
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="4" onClick={this.toggleModal}>
              <Icon type="logout" />
              <span>Log out</span>
            </Menu.Item>
          </Menu>
        </Sider>
        <Layout>
          <Header style={{ background: "#fff", paddingLeft: "20px" }}>
            <Icon
              className="trigger"
              type={this.state.collapsed ? "menu-unfold" : "menu-fold"}
              onClick={this.toggle}
            />
          </Header>
          <Content
            style={{
              padding: 24,
              background: "#fff",
              minHeight: 280
            }}
          >
            <Modal
              title="Log out"
              visible={this.state.modalVisible}
              onOk={this.handleOk}
              onCancel={this.handleCancel}
            >
              <p>Are you sure you want to log out?</p>
            </Modal>
            <BrowserRouter>
              <Switch>
                <Route to="/home" component={Home} exact />
                <Route to="/search" component={Search} exact />
                <Route to="/my-account" component={MyAccount} exact />
              </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
          </Content>
        </Layout>
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Dashboard);
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple issues in your code.

In `Route` you have written `to`,

```
<Route to="/home" component={Home} exact />
```

There is no `to` in `Route` you should use `path`

```
<Route path="/home" component={Home} exact />
```

Another issue is,

```
<Link to="dashboard/my-account" exact="true">
```

You should start your path with `/`, and don't write `exact` here

```
<Link to="/dashboard/my-account">
```

Again the above `Link` won't work because you don't have `Route` to handle this.

To make this work you should use `Link`'s like this,

```
<Link to="/home">
<Link to="/search">
<Link to="/my-account">
```

Another issue is,

```
this.props.history.push("/");
```

This also won't work as you don't have `Route` for path `/`.

To make this work, you should have `Route` like,

```
<Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
```

Refer [this](https://codeburst.io/getting-started-with-react-router-5c978f70df91) and [this](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) to learn more about routing.

---

**Update**

In `App.js` change your routes to this,

```
<BrowserRouter basename="dashboard"> //for basename refer second link above
    <Switch>
       <Route path="/" component={Dashboard} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

In `Dashboard.js`, remove `<BrowserRouter>` and have only `switch` like,

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/home" component={Home} exact />
  <Route path="/search" component={Search} exact />
  <Route path="/my-account" component={MyAccount} exact />
</Switch>
```

And your links should be,

```
<Link to="/home">
<Link to="/search">
<Link to="/my-account">
```

Comment: I made all the changes as you suggested but it still doesn't seems to work ps:- The ```this.props.history.push("/");
``` is for the landing page whose routes I have defined in another file

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox for this, so that I can have a look what changes you have done.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/upbeat-sky-seefo type dashboard into url to view the component